# How to move one shape without adding duplicates?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to print a cube to my panel and have it drop by 25px every 2 seconds using a timer, much like Tetris.
Problem is that when it drops and I call the method to draw the cube it just duplicates and keeps the first cube drawn on the panel. I have tried to invalidate the panel and clear the graphics but neither seems to work. Here is some of my code:

```
 public void drawCube()
    {
        float gridHeight = (float)GamePanel.Height;
        float gridWidth = (float)GamePanel.Width;


        SolidBrush blueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.LightBlue);
        Graphics cube = GamePanel.CreateGraphics();


        Rectangle upLeftCube = new Rectangle(locationX, locationY, 25, 25);
        Rectangle lowLeftCube = new Rectangle(locationX, upLeftCube.Y+25, 25, 25);
        Rectangle upRightCube = new Rectangle(upLeftCube.X+25, locationY, 25, 25);
        Rectangle lowRightCube = new Rectangle(lowLeftCube.X+25, upRightCube.Y+25, 25, 25);

        cube.DrawRectangle(outLinePen, upLeftCube);
        cube.DrawRectangle(outLinePen, lowLeftCube);
        cube.DrawRectangle(outLinePen, lowRightCube);
        cube.DrawRectangle(outLinePen, upRightCube);

        cube.FillRectangle(blueBrush, upLeftCube);
        cube.FillRectangle(blueBrush, lowLeftCube);
        cube.FillRectangle(blueBrush, lowRightCube);
        cube.FillRectangle(blueBrush, upRightCube);


    }


 public void startGame()
    {
        gameTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
        isGameRunning = true;

        gameTimer.Elapsed += MyTimedEvent;
        gameTimer.AutoReset = true;
        gameTimer.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void MyTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        drawCube();

        locationY += 25; 
    }
```

What I want is to basically simulate the game of Tetris where I am able to store blocks that have been placed while also adding new ones that the user can interact with an place.

Comment: You got to delete the shape first and then draw it in the new position. I don't see other solution

Comment: Use a WinForms timer.  The System.Timers.Timer isn't running on the GUI thread.  Use the Paint event (avoid CreateGraphics, it's a temporary drawing easily erased).  Use a DoubleBuffered panel to reduce flicker.

Comment: @LarsTech The thing about a paintevent is that I cant call it multiple times like a method which is why I drew everything in a certain method. Unless Im wrong on that

Comment: Just call `GamePanel.Invalidate();` in the Tick event to call the drawing code.

Comment: @LarsTech Wouldnt that wipe the whole panel and wipe away the blocks that I want stored permanently on the panel? It did work btw when I placed it at the top of my timer elapsed event

Comment: Again, you're using the wrong timer.  Tick event belongs to the WinForms timer.  And yes, you wipe your panel clear, and redraw everything.

Comment: @LarsTech so then how would I invalidate only the one graphic I have drawn on the screen instead of the whole panel?

Comment: There is no erase option.  You have to redraw everything.  Trying to only invalidate parts can be done, but it's complicated, and most of the time, not worth the effort.